# Alias with curried arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can you alias a method with curried arguments in Ruby (and possibly Rails)?

```
def say(name)
  puts "Hi, I'm #{ name }"
end

alias_method :introduce_john, :say, "John"

introduce_john # puts "Hi, I'm John"
```

Comment: How can you Currize a method that is already monadic? And in what sense can you Currize a method? What type would the return value be?

Answer (score 1):

Not by default, but it is easy enough to create one:

```
class Object
  def self.curried_alias_method(new, original, *pre_args)
    define_method(new) do |*args|
      send(original, *pre_args, *args)
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
class Foo
  def say(name)
    puts "Hi, I'm #{ name }"
  end

  curried_alias_method :introduce_john, :say, "John"
end

Foo.new.introduce_john
# prints "Hi, I'm John"
```